How to deal with a faulted NSManagedObject in a SwiftUI .task{} that won't unfault?
Sometimes and unpredictably within an async .task{} a NSManagedObject @State var has become faulted, and then is not unfaulted when the object's members are referenced. How can I figure out why it has faulted, or prevent it from faulting, or forcibly unfault it? My app needs to support iOS 16. Thank you
This example uses a Core Data store named "TestCoreDataTask" that has a single "Item" entity with a single "timestamp" attribute of type "Date". To reproduce the issue 1) tap the Add button, 2) wait 5 seconds, 3) sometimes a faulted sheetData.item is printed in the log.
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var sheetData : SheetData?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Add")
            .onTapGesture {
                let item = Item(context: viewContext)
                item.timestamp = Date()
                try? viewContext.save()
                sheetData = SheetData(item: item)
            }
        }
        .overlay(
            EmptyView()
                .fullScreenCover(item: $sheetData) { sheet in
                    Sheet(sheetData: $sheetData)
                }
        )
    }
}

struct SheetData: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let item : Item?
}

struct Sheet: View {
    @Binding var sheetData : SheetData?
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(sheetData?.item?.timestamp ?? Date())")
        .task { @MainActor in
            do {
                try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
                print("Sheet \(sheetData?.item?.timestamp)") // sometimes this is a fault!
            } catch is CancellationError {
                print("Task was cancelled")
            } catch {
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture { dismiss() }
    }
}

@main
struct TestCoreDataTaskApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TestCoreDataTask")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}


not sure what your question is, but have you tried moving the .fullScreenCover(...) out of the overlay. Also there seemed to be no reasons for having @Binding var sheetData : SheetData? in your Sheet view, try just a let.

Hi the fullscreen cover works ok, the problem is that sheetData?.item is not unfaulted when it's used.

Try removing EmptyView that looks suspect.

Hi mahal, that does not seem to be the issue

Using @State/@Binding is for value types, which coredata classes are not. NSManagedObject classes also implement ObservableObject, so use @ObservedObject directly instead and remove the SheetData wrapper struct.
